# TypeError: I.default.createNode is not a function.(In ‘I.default.createNode(this._nodeID,c({},this._nodeConfig))’,‘I.default.createNode’ is undefined)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

[image]

Getting this error after updated the 'react-native-reanimated' package while deploying to the emulator.